# Как работает InputStream и OutputStream в Java

Tags: java, java-output-stream

В Java потоки ввода-вывода `InputStream` и `OutputStream` представляют собой концепцию работы с внешним миром, будь то файл на диске, экран монитора, сетевое подключение или принтер. То есть всего, что выходит за пределы приложения.

Если я правильно понимаю, то в компьютере все в конечном итоге представляет собой поток байтов, и Stream-ы унифицируют работу над этим всем. Просто для каждого периферийного устройства я пишу свою реализацию `read()` и `write()`.

Есть конкретные классы - например `FileOutputStream`, который работает конкретно с файлами на диске. В нем в `write()`-методе используется native-метод, который осуществляет работу по записи данных в файл.

Но, например, я хочу работать с файлом по ftp. Или хочу вывести файл на печать через принтер. При таком концепте я должен делать это все через те же `OutputStream`. Как я должен написать реализацию класса `OutputStream`, а конкретно метода `write()`, чтобы отправить поток байтов в принтер? Или же в другой файл через ftp-соединение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OutputStream`, как и `InputStream` являются абстрактными классами, то есть не содержат реализации одного или более методов.

Конкретно в классе `OutputStream` отсутствует реализация метода:

```
public abstract void write(int oneByte) throws IOException;
```

Однако в документации говорится

> All output stream subclasses should override **both**
>     `write(int)` and `write(byte[],int,int)`, `write(byte[],int,int)`. The
>     three argument overload is necessary for bulk access to the data. This is
>     much more efficient than byte-by-byte access.

То есть обязательно необходимо реализовать запись одного байта и массива байт.

Таким образом вам необходимо унаследовать абстрактный класс `OutputStream` и реализовать передачу байтов устройству в методах `write`. Это не обязательно должен быть `native` метод, ваш класс может содержать высокоуровневое определение интерфейса взаимодействия с устройством, например через библиотеки, которые реализуют подключение к устройству и организуют передачу байт.

Пример записи в байт напрямую в принтер (на порту "/dev/usb/lp0") на языке `Java`:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/dev/usb/lp0"));
writer.write(new String("Hello world").getBytes());
writer.close();
```

Однако не уверен что у Java будет достаточно прав, поэтому привожу эквивалент на `C`:

```
int main()
{
  FILE *printer = fopen("/dev/usb/lp0", "w");
  fprintf(printer, "Hello World.\n\f");
  fflush(printer);
  fclose(printer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: да, ясно что надо реализовать абстрактные методы. Но вопрос в том, как в конечном счете в реализации этих методов подключиться к принтеру, например? Без подключения сторонних библиотек, на голой Java своими руками. Ведь эти java-библиотеки тоже как-то реализованы?

Comment: Это уже относится к конкретным реализациям библиотек, они реализуют подключение через драйвера, которые обычно пишутся на C

Comment: На самом деле для того, чтобы понять как байты посылаются в принтер, достаточно понимать как они записываются на файловую систему, по сути передача байт принтеру может оказаться идентичной. На самом деле все потоки пишут в файл, даже консоль вывода, это тоже файл, куда просто пишутся байты.

Comment: в linux все файл. Но я все-равно не могу записать данные в файл-вывод принтера. Это и хотелось бы понять

Comment: если его найти, то можно и в него записать как раз таки

Comment: но это если у вас принтер настроен и подключен на этот порт